# Reloading external scripts (ie. google maps) in jquery mobile / phonegap

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have an app built with jquery mobile and packaged with phonegap.  I'm running into the problem where if a user is to start my application in airplane mode (or just without a network connection) then turns a connection on / gains a connection google maps will not load, unless of course killing the app completely and relaunching.

The method I tried to resolve this was just reloading the page using the following...

```
if(checkOnlineStatus()){
            $.mobile.changePage( './index.html',
                {
                  allowSamePageTransition : true,
                  transition              : 'none',
                  showLoadMsg             : false,
                  reloadPage              : true,
                  changeHash              : false
                }
              );
        }
        else{
            alert("Application requires a network connection.  Please check your settings and retry."); 
        }
```

This doesn't seem to reload any scripts whether I include them in the data-role="page" or not.  I'm storing google maps script right before the `</body>` tag although I've tried this method storing it in the page element as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a last-resort solution and won't work for everyone, but in my case it works fine.  I replaced the changePage with an entire reload of the window...

```
 window.location.reload(true);
```

This forces a fresh reload from the server.